# Rails find_by accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I could be missing something simple, but how can I find a record by a non persisted attribute?

**Example**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  attr_accessor :slug

  def slug
    title.parameterize
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the only way to do this is to iterate through all the records until you find your target, as in:

```
def self.find_by_slug(slug)
   Post.select("title").detect { |post| post.slug == slug }
end
```

There's probably alternate ways of expressing that same logic, but I think they'll all require a lot of Ruby iteration. So if you want it to be efficient for large numbers of Posts, it'd be better to persist the attribute.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing in the interest of time and I guess that makes sense. Thanks for the confirmation Dan.